# Simple response to あなたはばんごはんを食べて、なにをしますか

Tags: sentence

> あなたは ばんごはんを 食べて、なにを しますか。

This seems to be saying "what do you do while eating dinner?" How to reply "I just eat"?　Does it make sense to say nothing?

Comment: Please stick to one question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

> あなたはばんごはんを食べて、なにをしますか。
>   This seems to be saying "what do you do while eating dinner?"

It seems to be asking "What do you do after eating dinner?" (*lit.* "You eat dinner, and what do you do?")... though it would be more natural to say it as 「あなたはばんごはんを｛食べて**から**/食べ**たあと**｝、なにをしますか？」 or 「あなたはばんごはん**のあと**、なにをしますか？」

<sub>"What do you do while eating dinner?" would be more like 「あなたはばんごはんを食べ**ながら**、なにをしますか？」</sub>

> How to reply "I just eat"?

"I just eat" would be like 「食べるだけです。」 but I don't think it answers the question. You could instead reply with 「[some activity you usually do after dinner]+(し)ます。」, as in:

> 「テレビをみます。」 I watch TV.
>   「ゲームをします。」 I play games.
>   「ねます。」 I go to bed.
>   「シャワーをあびて、ねます。」 I take a shower and go to bed.

Answer (score 0):

First - yes, please stick to once question per post. But I'll try and briefly address each of your questions.

> あなたは ばんごはんを 食べて、なにを しますか。

A verb in the ~て　form is a continuative form. So ばんごはんをたべて ...... does not indicate "while you eat" in the slightest. It does indicate that you eat, and then do something else.

> どこへ なにを しに行きますか。

Basically means where are you going and what are you doing there. どこへ means "to where", and 何をしに行きますか means "what are you doing to go do". Put those together...

> あなたは どうして 日本語を べんきょうしていますか

どうして means why. So This whole sentence is "Why are you studying Japanese".

> 子どもの時、たいてい どこで あそびましたか。

子どもの時 means "when you were a child". And you are right on the rest of the translation. But when you reply you have to say 公園｛こうえん｝**で**あそびました。not **を**あそびました。

Also - many of these questions could be figured out with a little bit of googling/use of a dictionary... so take some time to look up so vocab before you post here. Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: thanks for the post but you didn't actually answer my question though someone has now edited it to not be a question anymore but a statement i for the most part was able to translate the sentences myself that was not my question.

Comment: @Faust Please only ask one question per question.  Your post contained multiple questions, so I had to remove the unrelated text from the post.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you want to say `what do you do while eating dinner?` A correct sentence is the following.

> あなたは ばんごはんを 食べて **いるとき**、なにを しますか。

Then if you want to say `I just eat`,

> 食べるだけです

Comment: So, what new pieces of information does your short answer give us that have not already been given by the previous answers?

Comment: I gave a straight and short answer to his question because I think other answers are too verbose